# Can I use a github action to rename a file?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I want to be able to update a GitHub page at a scheduled time. Only way I've thought of is to rename the updated file at the scheduled time to index and delete the previous index. Is there a way for actions to delete or rename files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mv` from Linux command:

```
mv oldfile.txt newfile.txt
```

Here's how it will look in the workflow (YML) file:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Rename file 
        run: mv oldfile.txt newfile.txt

      - name: Delete file 
        run: rm -f file.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It successfully runs but doesn't do anything.

Comment: I got it. I wasn't pushing the changes at the end of the action.